# Captcha generated from image doesn't always put string into session

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, session, captcha

I'm using a .NET captcha where the captcha image is created from a file, like this:
myFile.aspx has this line:
    < img src="/CImage.aspx" />

The calling file (codebehind is VB) always loads the captcha generated image. CImage.aspx is C#. Again, an image is always returned and displayed.

CImage.aspx.cs puts a string variable into session and my calling page compares what the user entered from a text box to what CImage.aspx.cs puts into session. Often, the page is crashing because there isn't anything in session. However, captchaImage.aspx always writes the image.

My page calling using CImage.aspx is in VB.

Why would there "sometimes" be a session variable to compare but often there is not. (Not unless you refresh the page)

CImage.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
public partial class CImage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a random code and store it in the Session object.
        this.Session["CaptchaImageText"] = GenerateRandomCode();
        // Create a CAPTCHA image using the text stored in the Session object.
        RandomImage ci = new RandomImage(this.Session
            ["CaptchaImageText"].ToString(), 300, 75);
        // Change the response headers to output a JPEG image.
        this.Response.Clear();
        this.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        // Write the image to the response stream in JPEG format.
        ci.Image.Save(this.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        // Dispose of the CAPTCHA image object.
        ci.Dispose();
    }

    // Function to generate random string with Random class.
    private string GenerateRandomCode()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        string s = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < 5;j++)
        {
            int i = r.Next(3);
            int ch;
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    ch = r.Next(0, 9);
                    s = s + ch.ToString();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ch = r.Next(65, 90);
                    s = s + Convert.ToChar(ch).ToString();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ch = r.Next(97, 122);
                    s = s + Convert.ToChar(ch).ToString();
                    break;
                default:
                    ch = r.Next(97, 122);
                    s = s + Convert.ToChar(ch).ToString();
                    break;
            }
            r.NextDouble();
            r.Next(100, 1999);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: session has time limit, you can extend session time or try another way : store the random code in cookie

Comment: If I load the page, complete it in, say, 10 seconds, it still produces the error. I will try the cookie route. Thank you.